# How to select two different values from a table with different conditions in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
userdata

guidUser  username  
-----------------
12        plr1        
13        plr2
14        plr3
15        plr4

games

id  guidUser1  guidUser2
-------------------------
1       12        13
2       15        14
```

I want to select names of players from the same userdata table based on their guid.

The result I'm trying to obtain is:

```
id  guidUser1   username  guidUser2  username2
--------------------------------------------
1       12        plr1        13        plr2
2       15        plr4        14        plr3
```

If the value was only one I could do

```
SELECT g.id, g.guidUser1, u.username, g.guidUser2 from games g, userdata u WHERE g.guidUser1=u.guidUser1
```

But how I can obtain the second username 'username2'?

Comment: Have you tried joining `userdata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join twice.  Each join to the `userdata` table brings in one username:

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    g.guidUser1,
    u1.username,
    g.guidUser2,
    u2.username AS username2
FROM games g
INNER JOIN userdata u1
    ON g.guidUser1 = u1.guidUser
INNER JOIN userdata u2
    ON g.guidUser2 = u2.guidUser;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: good solution! Thank you! I have still a problem with my real query, may you can take a quick look to the edit i made?

Comment: I can't answer your updated question, because you have changed the table structure.  But, you appear to be mixing implicit and explicit join syntax, which is not a good thing.  You might want to ask a new question, and then reference this one.

Comment: Yea, I checked and removing the mix and doing two inner join it works! Thank you! I'll remove the edit for it may be misleading for people passing by

Answer (score 4):

You can try below - using joining of multiple instance of userdata table

```
 SELECT g.id, g.guidUser1, u.username, g.guidUser2 u1.username as username2
    from 
    games g inner join userdata u on g.guidUser1=u.guidUser
    inner join userdata u1 on g.guidUser2=u1.guidUser
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by joining to the userdata table a second time.

Note I've used modern INNER JOIN syntax to make it clearer what the join clauses apply to. I suggest that you should aim to use the modern syntax wherever possible to make your code clearer and cleaner.

```
SELECT 
  g.id, 
  g.guidUser1, 
  u1.username AS username1, 
  g.guidUser2,
  u2.username AS username2
FROM
  games g 
  INNER JOIN userdata u1
    ON g.guidUser1 = u.guidUser
  INNER JOIN userdata u2
    ON g.guidUser2 = 2.guidUser
```